# Hiding code block lines in vs code editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have these weird lines on all my code that seem to highlight the code block. How do i turn them off? I'm on version 1.30

Link: https://ibb.co/z5Tt6t4

So the white lines on the left. What are they called and how can i turn them off?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can hide the indentation guide lines by adding these settings to vscode's `settings.json` file:

```json
"editor.guides.indentation": false,
"editor.guides.highlightActiveIndentation":false,
```

`"editor.guides.indentation": false,` will turn off all editor guides including and regardless of the `"editor.guides.highlightActiveIndentation"` setting.

[Prior to 1.61.0](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_61#_indentation-guides-settings), these settings had different keys:

```json
"editor.renderIndentGuides": false,
"editor.highlightActiveIndentGuide": false,
```

You can also change their colors (including transparent #0000):

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorIndentGuide.background": "#ff0000",
    "editorIndentGuide.activeBackground": "#ff0000",
}
```